# adding events to facebook users profile using facebook graph api from a 3rd party web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-media

Need to send the event information to the users facebook profile, using jquery or javascript. A user logins into my web site and creates an event, but those event details has to be sent to his/her profile so that he can send invitation to his/her friends and they can RSVP to the events, my web site is based on jquery and javascript and have used java as middle ware and mysql 5.1 at the back end.

I just got with this when I googled http://www.triadwebcrafters.com/blog/?p=140

but its on cold fusion,

Is any one already done this before or any library or tutorials available.

Kindly help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have your user logged in to facebook via the javascript facebook sdk.

next, post to his profile:

```
function publish_it()
{
 var publish = {
  method: 'stream.publish',
  message: 'your message',
  attachment: {
    name: 'invitation',
    description: 'a very pretty invitation!',
    href: 'href to the invitation',
    media: [
              { type: 'image', src: 'http://site.com/image.jpg', href: 'href to the invitation'}
              ]
  },
  action_links: [
    { text: 'come as well!', href: 'href to the invitation' }
  ]};

FB.ui(publish);    

  }
```

Comment: thank you T4u,yes user have to log in, I will do it, if I get any issues I will post it here, kindly help me out, since I am newbie/novice for facebook api's. Thank u so much

Comment: I can just update my facebook wall with this code, but I need to add events to create an event page thats facebook.com/Events how do I that

Comment: @Jeevan Dongre, adding events by an application is entirely a new topic. i suggest you to look it up in the facebook api and try to do that by yourself. if you still need help, create a new topic and send me the link (you can just comment here), i'll try to help you though i have never done that.

Comment: hello @T4u: I have added a question at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867450/adding-events-information-to-the-facebook-profile-from-3rd-party-website and also described my problem. Kindly help me to solve it.