# adding events information to the facebook profile from 3rd party website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to add events information to the facebook users profile from a 3rd party website using Javascript SDK provided by facebook. I just googled for few tutorials and I got this links

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-ask-for-extended-permission-in-your-facebook-application/32/

http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-create-facebook-events-using-graph-api/49/#using_the_js-sdk

I tried with the combination of login logout and session handling

this is the code which I am run just to test whether it works or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.init({
        appId: '207712505927107', 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true
    });

    /* All the events registered */
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    // do something with response
        login();
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        // do something with response
        logout();
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
    {
        if (response.session)
        {
            // logged in and connected user, someone you know
            login();
        }
    });
};

(function() 
{
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol
            + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

function login()
{
    FB.api('/me', function(response)
    {
        document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block";

        var loggedInMessage = response.name + " successfully logged in!";
        document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = loggedInMessage;
    });
}

function logout()
{
    document.getElementById('login').style.display = "none";
}

//addevent to facebook profile 

function addevents()
{
    FB.api('/me/events', 'post', {
        name:          "JS-SDK Event",
        start_time:    1272718027,
        location:      "Beirut",
        privacy_type:  "OPEN"
    }, function(resp) {
        alert(resp.id);
    });
}
</script>

<p>
    <fb:login-button
        autologoutlink="true" 
        perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,create_event">
    </fb:login-button>
</p>

<p>
    <a href="#" onclick="addevents(); return false;">Add Events</a>
</p>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<div id="login" style ="display:none"></div>
<div id="name"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the add event page I am getting "undefined". Iam not able to add events to facebook profle. Kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try your code again, and maybe console.log(resp) in your callback method for the addevents function.  I tested your code on fbrell.com and it seemed to work perfectly and as expected.

**edit:** after a little research (and your fixed code..) I found that the fb:login button doesn't ensure that your application has the correct permissions that the perms parameter requests.  We find this out when we do a Graph request and it fails.  So we catch the error, and then launch the Login modal via the `FB.login` method, and ask for the `create_event` permission.  When the user accepts that dialog, we retry creating the event.

```
<fb:login-button
    autologoutlink="true" 
    perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,create_event">
</fb:login-button>
<a href="#" id="create_event" onclick="create_event();">create</a>

<script>
FB.XFBML.parse();
document.getElementById('create_event').onclick = function() { create_event(); }
function create_event()
{
    FB.api('/me/events', 'post', {
        name:          "JS-SDK Event",
        start_time:    1272718027,
        location:      "Anywhere USA",
        privacy_type:  "OPEN"
    }, function(resp) {

        if (typeof resp.error != 'undefined')
        { /*this failed. most likely because we don't have the extended permission
            for create_event. so lets check for it, ask for it, and try to create
            the event again.  but first, we'll make sure that the error message says
            something about 'create_event' so we don't launch an infinite loop
          */
            if (resp.error.message.match(/create_event/))
            {
                FB.login(function(response)
                {
                    if (response.session 
                        && response.status == 'connected' 
                        && response.perms.match(/create_event/))
                    {
                        //this user is connected & we have create event permission.
                        create_event();
                    }
                },
                {
                    perms: 'create_event'
                });
            }
        }    
    });
}
</script>
```

Working code on fbrell.com: http://fbrell.com/saved/17c7b60eab91e6736a2a10c87d53c5b8

Comment: hey thanks but i figured out the problem, i am posting it below as answer you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '207712505927107', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

    /* All the events registered */
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        // do something with response
        login();
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        // do something with response
        logout();
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            // logged in and connected user, someone you know
            login();
        }
    });
};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

function login(){
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = response.name + " succsessfully logged in!";
    });
}

function logout(){
    document.getElementById('login').style.display = "none";
}

//add events 
function addevents() {
    FB.api('/me/events','post',{
        name:"awesome event",
        start_time:1272718027,
        location:"Bengaluru",
        privacy_type:"OPEN",
        description:"U r    invited !!!"
    }, function(resp) {
        document.write(resp.id);
    });
}

//checking persmission

function check_perm() {

    FB.api({ method: 'users.hasAppPermission', ext_perm: 'create_event' }, function(resp)
    {
        if (resp === "1") {
            alert('Permission granted');
        } else {
            alert("Permission not granted");
        }
    });
}

</script>

<p>Please click on Login button first </p>
<p><fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="create_event"></fb:login-button></p>

<p> Please click on check permissions first </p>
<a href="#" onclick="check_perm(); return false;"> check permissions </a>
<p> now u r all set to add events to facebook </p>

<p>
    <a href="#" onclick="addevents(); return false;"> Add Events </a>

</p>

<br /><br /><br />

<div id="login" style ="display:none"></div>
<div id="name"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So the login button doesn't verify that you have the permissions you request, just that you're logged in. is that what i'm seeing? if so, i'll add that to my answer so it is complete.

Comment: yes exactly JIMR, even I was in that confusion, thanks to all the blogggers around then world, the blogs are more informative then the facebook documentation. !!! thanks for the help!!!